# Book about a bio fleet

Tags: story-identification, books

I'm looking for a book I read.

All I remember is that it featured a bio fleet with the ships fighting among themselves.
I think that everyone is female.

The book starts with the protagonist waking up after she was killed. And it turns out she is killed over and over again trying to infiltrate another ship.

The ship's themselves provide nutrition to the populace and when someone dies she gets thrown into a tunnel which goes all the way to the center of the ship where the body is digested.

At some point in the book the protagonist is thrown there and needs to make her way back up.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  What do you mean by "bio fleet?"  Are the ships themselves organic?  You should also check out the [suggestions for good story-id questions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/101407) to see if they help you remember anything else you can [edit] into your question.  For example, when did you read it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Is it [The Stars are Legion](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/29090844-the-stars-are-legion) by Kameron Hurley?  In particular, [this review](https://www.theverge.com/2017/2/8/14516168/kameron-hurley-the-stars-are-legion-science-fiction-book-review) talks about the protagonist making repeated attempts to board an enemy ship and eventually finding herself a tunnel-like recycler deep in one of the organic ships.

Goodreads summary:

> Somewhere on the outer rim of the universe, a mass of decaying world-ships known as the Legion is traveling in the seams between the stars. For generations, a war for control of the Legion has been waged, with no clear resolution.  As worlds continue to die, a desperate plan is put into motion.
>
> Zan wakes with no memory, prisoner of a people who say they are her family. She is told she is their salvation - the only person capable of boarding the Mokshi, a world-ship with the power to leave the Legion. But Zan's new family is not the only one desperate to gain control of the prized ship. Zan finds that she must choose sides in a genocidal campaign that will take her from the edges of the Legion's gravity well to the very belly of the world.
>
> Zan will soon learn that she carries the seeds of the Legion's destruction - and its possible salvation. But can she and her ragtag band of followers survive the horrors of the Legion and its people long enough to deliver it?
>
> In the tradition of The Fall of Hyperion and Dune, The Stars are Legion is an epic and thrilling tale about tragic love, revenge, and war as imagined by one of the genre's most celebrated new writers.

Comment: Yes! I have the book and it starts exactly as the question describes. RoamingShroob, I can edit a quote into your answer if you would like me to.

Comment: @JohnRennie  Yes, quotes would be helpful.  Please feel free to add what quotes you feel are relevant.  Thanks.

Comment: It was actually in my kindle history but I missed it because I was sure it was a different book (The Stars My Destination). Thanks.